# Report is not generated, If I run my test cases(JUnit) through Maven?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I am New to JUnit and Maven. I am running my JUnit testcases through maven. Build is getting succeed but index.html is not generated. How can I generate the index.html?

This is my project structure after build succeeded.

[image]

And My POM.xml is as follows,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestCodeCoverage</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyMavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>

        <dependencies>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>2.12</version>   
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <configuration>                     
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
         </includes>
        </configuration>    
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
  </build>

     <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                    <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

   <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <reports>
              <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting `maven-surefire-report-plugin` to generate the report, then it will do so, only if you run the `site` goal (`mvn site`).    Otherwise, as you can see, the `reports` are available in `target\surefire-reports` folder.

Comment: So what should I need to change my POM.xml to view reports in target\surefire-reports folder.

Comment: I am really sorry, I can't understand. Can you please explain it briefly

Comment: You should run the site goal after you have run your tests. So mvn test site should do the trick.

Comment: I tried, but my maven installation path is in "C" directory , my workspace directory is in "E" directory. How can I run mvn site command from "C" directory which will refer the POM.xml which is located in "E:/TestProject/POM.xml"? please help me

Comment: Is there any way to run mvn site through eclipse by using any configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to the directory where you pom.xml exist.Using this command `cd E:/TestProject` and then run the site goal. For e.g. `mvn site`